# call conditional method from constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something really simple but not able to achieve this.

```
var Dummy = function() {
    self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {

        if(self.render) {
            self.render(); 
        }
    }, 10);
};
var test = new Dummy();
test.render = function() {
    console.log('Make constructor call this method? ');   
}
```

How can I make this work without settimeout?

**Goal: Based on the function names attached to instance, I want to call them in particular order.**

eg:

```
var Dummy = function() {
    if(function1) {
       function1();
    }
    if(function2) {
       function2();
    }
};
```

Comment: got it, can I make this work without timeout?

Comment: You cannot call something that does not exist. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: it there any alternative pattern to achieve this?

Comment: Again, you cannot call something that does not exist. Again, *why* are you trying to do this? *What* is it really that you are trying to do?

Comment: Achieve what? Maybe pass the render function as an argument to the constructor?

Comment: Unless you explicitly say what you want to achieve nobody will be able to help you, mainly because your code makes no sense.

Comment: updated question now

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me, and unless I'm missing something it works when I try it.  @JS-JMS-WEB you should probably define the `test.render` function before you create the new `Dummy` object though, to avoid a race condition.

Comment: What do you mean by 'calling them' in particular order??

Comment: And what does "Based on the function attached to instance" mean?

Comment: Biggest XY problem I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if what you want to do is call multiple functions (in order) when you instantiate an `object instance of Dummy`:

```
var Dummy = function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "function") {
             arguments[i]();
        }
     }
}

var function1 = function() { console.log('Func 1 executed!'); }
var function2 = function() { console.log('Func 2 executed!'); }

var d = new Dummy(func1, func2, 'maybe a string also');

// log
'Func1 executed!'
'Func2 executed!'
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do! Couldn't explain it properly I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You question isn't entirely clear, but I assume you have a function that you want to have called as soon as your object has been instantiated. The simplest way to do this is to *pass the function as an argument*.

Something like:

```
var Dummy = function(myFunction) {
    self = this;
    self.render = myFunction;     // if you want to be able to call it again later
    self.render();                // if you want to call it now
};

var test = new Dummy(function() {
    console.log('Make constructor call this method? ');   
});

var anotherTest = new Dummy(function() {
    console.log("this instance will have a different render function");
});
```

Now, of course, this can be extended to handle any number of functions passed in:

```
var Dummy = function(func1, func2) {
   // Note: you may want to check the arguments actually are functions
   if (func1) {
       func1();
   }
   if (func2) {
       func2();
   }
}

var test = new Dummy(function() { console.log("1"); },
    function() { console.log("2"); });
```

Or you could pass in an array of functions in the order you want them executed:

```
var Dummy = function(funcArray) {
    for (var i=0; i < funcArray.length; i++) {
        funcArray[i]();
    }
}

var test = new Dummy([function() { console.log("1"); },
    function() { console.log("2"); }]);
```

Or you could pass in an object with the functions (and names) you want:

```
var Dummy = function(funcObject) {
    if (funcObject.func1) {
        funcObject.func1();
    }
    if (funcObject.func2) {
        funcObject.func2();
    }
}

var test = new Dummy({ func1 : function() { console.log("1"); },
    func2: function() { console.log("2"); });
```

Comment: Like the idea of passing object. That's how backbone does it!

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you are adding `render()` method on the `Dummy instance` (`test`) and you are not even calling that `render()` method.

I think you need to change to the following (assuming you don't want to use `prototype` to create the `render()` method):

```
var Dummy = function() {

    this.render = function() {
        console.log('Make constructor call this method called? ');   
    };

    self = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(self);
        self.render(); 
    }, 10);
};
var test = new Dummy();
```